# Design a webpage without code (drag and drop)

Tags: windows-7, web-development

I'm looking for software that can design a beautiful webpage without coding, just by dragging and dropping.

I'm looking for something similar to [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html), but for webpages.

Comment: You mean the editor will just generates HTML? If yes, HTML5 or previous version? What means beautiful webpage, this is very vague.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is Adobe Dreamweaver. With its WYSIWYG editor it is very easy to drag and drop elements onto the page. You may need to modify a bit of the HTML the fully customize it but a lot less than any other app out there.